# ob.derived2::i has no value. But when I compile this program its value becomes 33 and overall sum is 88

Tags: c++

`ob.derived2::i` has no value. But when I compile this program its value becomes 33 and overall sum is 88. Can you explain please?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base { public: int i; };
class derived1 :  public base { public: int j; };
class derived2 : public base { public: int k; };
class derived3 : public derived1, public derived2 {
    public: int sum;
};

int main(){

    derived3 ob;
    ob.derived1::i = 10; 
    ob.j = 20;
    ob.k = 30;

    ob.sum = ob.derived2::i + ob.j + ob.k;
    cout << ob.sum;

}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything like "no value". Uninitialized variables have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value. Using such a value lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Reading a variable that has not been assigned a value is [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) - it's not zero or any other well defined value. And invoking UB is *bad*, not just for the calculation in question but for the *entire program*. The compiler is allowed to treat all of the program as invalid if it invokes UB *anywhere* and may generate whatever code it pleases for all of it. In short; avoid UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, your classes have the members uninitialized.

However, your concern is that you set `i` via `derived1` and get it via `derived2` and you assume it should be the same value.  But `derived1` and `derived2` both inherit from `base` so both have their own `i`. So `derived3` have two `i`s.

To get your expected behaviour, derive `derived2` from `derived1` instead of from `base`.